# Concatenate string from a variable in XAML Bindings of Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In a Xamarin.Forms project, I need to concatenate a Localized String value with a binding of a string property,

I want to achieve something like,

```
<Label Text="{Binding Name}", 
       StringFormat='Created By {0}' />
```

but **Created By** string should come from,

```
LocalizedStrings.CreatedBy
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This can be achieved by using the [`FormattedText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.label.formattedtext?view=xamarin-forms) property of `Label`. Did you try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the xaml, add a name to reference the label,

```
<Label x:Name="myLabel" />
```

in the code-behind,

```
myLabel.SetBinding(
    Label.TextProperty,
    new Binding(nameof(MyModal.Name), stringFormat: $"{LocalizedStrings.CreatedBy} {{0}}"));
```

this way we can format the binding string properties with variable values.

**Alternative Approach:**

You can also use **FormattedText** property of the **Label** as follows, *however this is not an optimized approach*.

Import **LocalizedStrings** to **xmlns:Resources**, then,

```
<Label>
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="{x:Static Resources:LocalizedStrings.CreatedBy}" />
            <Span Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat=' {0}'}"/>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's achievable by using the `ForamttedText` Property of `Label`. [MS Docs link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.label.formattedtext?view=xamarin-forms)

```
<Label>
    <Label.FormattedText>
        <FormattedString>
            <Span Text="{x:Static Resources:LocalizedStrings.CreatedBy}" />
            <Span Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat=' {0}'}"/>
        </FormattedString>
    </Label.FormattedText>
</Label>
```

where **Resources** is an import for **LocalizedStrings**

Comment: The **Created By** text should come from a localized string variable as per the question

Comment: `<Span Text="Created By "/>` should be `<Span Text="{x:Static LocalizedStrings.CreatedBy}" />`